# What's in the spike room in the castle?

Tags: candy-box-2

I've made it through all the other rooms, but I can't find anything in the room with the spikes on the floor. I have rocket boots and jumped around all over the place, nothing found. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't think there's anything in this room.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing else inside that room, only spikes.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much nothing. It's pretty much useless UNLESS you have the pink enchanted gloves and the boots of introspection. Since entering that room counts as engaging in a quest, you can use the boots to stand in place and just wait while your health replenishes at a faster rate.

Answer (score -3):

Honestly, there is really nothing in this room other then spikes so to be honest, you might as well just stay out of there unless you want to replenish your health.