# How do I get the boots of luck in Candy Box 2?

Tags: candy-box-2

Supposedly you need to have the boots of luck to pass the spike room and you need to finish the cyclopes puzzle to get the boots but I already finished the puzzle 4 times and I can't find it....so what do I do?
How do I get the boots of luck?

Comment: I don't recall any such item called the "boots of luck" in Candy Box 2... There's the Leather Boots, the Boots of Introspection, and the Rocket Boots, but no Boots of Luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's in the spike room in the castle?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137176/whats-in-the-spike-room-in-the-castle)  You'll notice the answer that mentioned "Boots of luck" is downvoted - that's because it's made-up.  There are no boots of luck.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft The other question is certainly related, but I wouldn't call it a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

You have been misled, I'm afraid. *Candy Box 2* features no such thing as "Boots of Luck".

However, you can get more information about the spike room [with the help of this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/137176/).

Answer (score 3):

There are no "boots of luck" in Candy Box 2 and there is nothing to find in the spike room.